# Python dice class that returns individual rolls

Tags: python, list, class, return, subclass

I'm trying to make a Die() class, with a DiceShaker() subclass. The DiceShaker() subclass is supposed to take multiple copies of the Die() class, roll them, and then return the individual rolls. Here is my code for Die().

```
class Die(object):
 'a class representing a Die'
  def __init__(self, sides=6):
     'initialize a die, default 6 sides'
      self.sides = sides

 def roll(self):
     'roll the dice'
      self.dieRoll = random.randint(1, self.sides)


 def get(self):
     'get the current value of the die'
      return self.dieRoll
```

Here is my code for DiceShaker().

```
class DiceShaker(Die):
'DiceShaker class'

def __init__(self,dieCount=1, dieSides=6, dieList = [], dieList2 = []):
    'initialize a dice shaker'
    Die.__init__(self,sides = 6) 
    self.dieCount = dieCount
    self.dieSides = dieSides
    self.dieList = dieList
    self.dieList2 = dieList2


def shake(self):
    'shake all the dice in the shaker'
    counter = 0
    dieList = [] 
    while counter != self.dieCount:
        self.dieList.append(Die.roll(self)) 
        counter = counter + 1
    return self.dieList 

def getIndividualRolls(self):
    'get a lsit of integers of all the individual die rolls'
    for items in self.dieList:
        self.dieList2.append(Die.get(self))
    return self.dieList2
```

getIndividualRolls() is supposed to return a list with all of the dice that were passed through shake(), but the list printed is always just one number. 
Example:

```
d=DiceShaker(3)
d.shake()
[None, None, None]
d.getIndividualRolls()
[3, 3, 3]
```

I have shake() returning [none] just so I know that the correct number of dice are going through, but I can't figure out how why getIndividualRolls() keeps printing out duplicates. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why is your `DiceShaker` a subclass of `Die`? This makes no sense. Subclassing is for `is a` relationships. `DiceShaker` isn't a type of `Die` (just like a `ShoppingCart` isn't a type of `CartItem`. Your relationship is compositional. `DiceShaker` has `Die`s (which you reflect with your `dieList`).

Comment: If you have a choice, you should be learning on Python 3. Python 2 is on its way out: https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DieShaker` class should just be a wrapper around a list of `Die` objects.

```
class Die(object):
    'a class representing a Die'
    def __init__(self, sides=6):
        'initialize a die, default 6 sides'
        self.sides = sides
        # You should make sure that by the time someone has created a Die object, 
        # all the attributes they might want to access have been defined
        self.roll()

   def roll(self):
       'roll the dice'
        self.dieRoll = random.randint(1, self.sides)

   # Note I got rid of Die.get 
   # Anyone who can call Die.get can see Die.dieRoll

class DiceShaker(object):
    def __init__(self, dice=()): # Note we avoid mutable default arguments
        self.dice = list(dice)   # Presumably it would be nice to add/remove dice

    def shake(self):
        for die in self.dice:
            die.roll()
        # return self.get_dice() 
        # It doesn't really make sense for this to return anything

    def get_dice(self):
        return [die.dieRoll for die in self.dice]
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be too long for a comment:

As an aside, you should really be learning on Python 3. Python 2 is [on the way out](https://pythonclock.org/). Everything below works in Python 3.

Why is your `DiceShaker` a subclass of `Die`? This makes no sense. Subclassing is for `is a` relationships. `DiceShaker` isn't a type of `Die` (just like a `ShoppingCart` isn't a type of `CartItem`). Your relationship is compositional. `DiceShaker` has `Die`s (which you reflect with your `dieList`). In this case `dieList` is all you need here. You don't need to inherit from `Die`.

The underlying reason why you get the same number rolled is because you inherited from die. By subclassing `Die`, you made `DiceShaker` behave like a `Die`. That means you could've called `ds.roll()` and `ds.get()` (where `ds = DiceShaker()`) and it would behave exactly the same as if you called it on a `Die`. This is effectively what you've done when you've wrote `Dice.get(self)`. That's equivalent to `self.get()` (since `DiceShaker` extends `Dice`). But `DiceShaker` is only one `Die`, not multiple. So calling `get()` will always return the same thing. What you've effectively done is the following:

```
die = Die()
die.roll()

for other_die in self.dieList:
    self.dieList2.append(die.get())  # note you're getting the same die each time
```

So to fix this, you don't need to inherit from `Die`. In fact you **shouldn't**. Instead compose `DieShaker` and `Die`. This means `DieShaker` should delegate to the `Die`s it contains (by calling `get` on them, *not itself*).

```
from random import randint

class Die:
    def __init__(self, sides=6):
        self.sides = sides

    def roll(self):
        self._rolled_value = randint(1, self.sides)

    def get_value_rolled(self):
        return self._rolled_value


class DieShaker:
    def __init__(self, num_die=1, num_die_sides=6):
        self.dice = [Die(num_die_sides) for _ in range(num_die)]

    def shake(self):
        for die in self.dice:
            die.roll()

    def get_values_rolled(self):
        return [die.get_value_rolled() for die in self.dice]
```

Note how in `get_values_rolled` (equivalent to your `DieShaker.getIndividualRolls`), we call `get_value_rolled` (equivalent to your `Die.get`) on each `Die` that our shaker contains (in the list `self.dice`).

Also note that I cleaned up your code in the following ways:

- It is convention in Python to use `snake_case` for variables/properties and functions
- I renamed a few of the functions to make their relationship more clear (`get_value_rolled` and `get_values_rolled`)
- I used [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) (ex. `[Die(num_die_sides) for _ in range(num_die)]` is the same thing as your while loop that `append`s to your `self.dieList`, but is more pythonic)
- I replaced `while` with a `for`. Typically in python you want to use a `for` when you're working with iterables (list `list`).
- I removed some of the optional arguments to your `DieShaker` constructor. For your purposes, it doesn't make much sense to allow them to be passed in (If you want to wade into the more technical, there is a reason why you'd do this, but for your purposes now, don't). It looks like you may think you need everything to be a parameter to `__init__`, but you don't. Instead of this (which actually [has a serious issue unrelated to the style/semantics](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)):

Bad:

```
def __init__(self, num_die=1, die_sides=6, dice = []):
    self.dice = dice
```

You probably should do this:

```
def __init__(self, num_die=1, die_sides=6):
    self.dice = []
```

- I removed your second list. You only need to maintain a list of die (since after calling `roll()` on each die, it will return the same thing for `get_value()` each time)